# Web Scrapping Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, web-scraping

Какую библиотеку можно использовать для скраппинга динамических данных? Например, библиотека request присылает страницу, где еще js скрипты не выполнены и часть информации отсутствует. Возможно ли это без использования headless browsers?

Comment: puppeeter - от Chrome

Answer (score 0):

На вскидку вот эти инструменты

http://www.nightmarejs.org/

https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver

https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs

> Возможно ли это без использования headless browsers?

Как вариант посмотреть на какие урлы уходят запросы и что приходит в ответ. А там уже смотреть что можно сделать с данными

Answer (score 0):

Если данные на страницу загружаются динамически, то можно попробовать собирать их прямо в JSON формате.
Открываем DevTools на вкладке Network, ставим фильтр XHR и смотрим запросы к бекенду. Найдя ссылку которая подгружает данные и используя request подгружаем эти данные.